# Sql Query inside Query with Distinct

Tags: sql

I need suggestion on

```
Select * 
From dbo.tblActivityDetails 
WHERE  (minWorked =0) 
   and Pillar = (
               select distinct Pillar 
               from dbo.tblActivityDetails 
               where EmpID=0067
                )
```

getting error

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

How to write a query to achieve above query results?

Comment: what outputs do you expect from the inner select and the query overall. There's a few ways to resolve the error but which one to do depends a lot on what you are trying to get out of each query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or SQlite? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here u have to use top 1... because distinct will give distinct results

```
Select * From dbo.tblActivityDetails WHERE  (minWorked =0) and Pillar = 
(select top 1 Pillar from dbo.tblActivityDetails where EmpID=0067)
```

or use Pillar in (in place of '=') expecting multiple values

```
Select * From dbo.tblActivityDetails WHERE  (minWorked =0) and Pillar in 
    (select distinct Pillar from dbo.tblActivityDetails where EmpID=0067)
```

Comment: Fantastic @Ravi, just changed '=' to 'In' resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: u can even directly use empid=0067 in main query... no need of sub query check

Comment: 0067 may come in many pillars so it won't help, i want all the pillar members where 0067 is a member

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IN` Or `EXISTS`

```
Select * From dbo.tblActivityDetails d
WHERE  (d.minWorked =0) and d.Pillar IN 
(select  d1.Pillar from dbo.tblActivityDetails d1 where d1.EmpID=0067)

Select * From dbo.tblActivityDetails d
WHERE  (d.minWorked =0) AND 
        EXISTS (select  1 from dbo.tblActivityDetails d1 
                        where d1.EmpID=0067 AND d.Pillar = d1.Pillar)
```

Comment: Heh, didn't even notice that meself :)

Comment: There are more Pillars so above query won't help

Comment: Why not? I think it's same as using `Pillar IN (...)`. Could you add a sample for more details

Comment: i want all the pillar members where 0067 is a member

Comment: @TriV although it's not mentioned in the question, I think OP means that he may have the same pillar with multiple empid's in the table and he wants all of those rows returned (with all of the empid's). With a simple-ish employee example. He could have employee name, manager stored. He wants to return all of the employees that have the same manager as employee x. The nested query returns the manager (pillar) of x(empid 0067) and the outer query returns all of the employees (multiple empid's) with the same manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte As (select distinct Pillar 
               from dbo.tblActivityDetails 
               where EmpID=0067)
Select * 
From dbo.tblActivityDetails As t
Join cte as c
On c.Pillar = t.pillar
WHERE minWorked = 0
```

That's off the top of my head - typed straight in, I may have goofed slightly on syntax but try and see :)

Comment: Thanks @rachel ambler

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query can return multiple rows so instead of = operator you have to use IN keyword 
Solution

```
select * From dbo.tblActivityDetails WHERE (minWorked =0) and Pillar in (select distinct Pillar from dbo.tblActivityDetails where EmpID=0067)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a Subquery...just go for

```html
Select * 
From dbo.tblActivityDetails 
WHERE minWorked =0 and EMPID=0067
```

Or just go for

```html
Select * 
From dbo.tblActivityDetails 
WHERE  (minWorked =0) 
   and Pillar in (
               select distinct Pillar 
               from dbo.tblActivityDetails 
               where EmpID=0067
                )
```